# How to add non-English words as text part to multi-part request in volley lib?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, multipart, rfc

I have a custom json request class to upload multi-part files to server this class in an Android application , it works fine when I add English words as keys and values(these keys and values are one part) but when I use any Arabic word, it writes unknown words like "'D*F*9". 
 
Before I write these values to ByteArrayOutputStream object, every thing works fine, and I can see Arabic words.
This is the get Body Content Type method for the all class

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=" + boundary;
    //return "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    //return "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8";
}
```

Here is the build Text Part method to construct the text part

```
 private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    Log.d("inside buildText", parameterName + " " + parameterValue);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}
```

And here the code I have used to debug these values

```
// just for debugging
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream  (bos.toByteArray()));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            Log.d("scanner ", scanner.next());
        }
```

I have read this  [RFC document](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) but I can't understand what the purpose of Content-Disposition and what does its values mean.

What should I edit in this code to get the Arabic values correctly ?

Should I change the content type in all parts or I can make every part has its content Type ?

Any help plz ?

Comment: `to upload multi-part files to server`? What is a multi-part file?

Comment: First part has an image and another one has some keys and values.

Comment: A file looks like that? Dont think so.

Comment: Do you want to see the constructor  ?

Comment: You should realise that multipart files do not exists. Only multipart messages. Or multipart upload or download. But files no.

Comment: I have already used it before to upload image with some params but when I use Arabic content it uploads strange characters. 
So Do you mean I use unrelated word which is file  or what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153051/discussion-between-khalid-ali-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer, the problem was in this line

```
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
```

So I updated it to

```
dataOutputStream.write(parameterValue.getBytes("utf-8"));
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

to get all un ASCII characters, and now it works fine for all languages.

Comment: I had this problem, this is solution. I appreciate you .

Answer (score 0):

```
private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    Log.d("inside buildText", parameterName + " " + parameterValue);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.write(parameterValue.getBytes("utf-8"));
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).