# Arabic Values in MySql database

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley, arabic

When i post data in arabic language from android then garbage values store in mysql database but when i send same data from postman then it correctly saved in mysql database following are the parameters :

```
{ 
strName=نلنلننب تبتبتب, 
strDescription=بتنبتبعبتب تبتبن بعنبتبنب تبهبتب, 
}
```

following values are stored in mysql database
[image]

Collation of my columns is utf8_general_ci in mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Arabic word in java server page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629624/how-to-display-arabic-word-in-java-server-page)

Comment: i'm talking about android volley

Comment: Issue is solved by this
[multi-part request in volley lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923102/how-to-add-non-english-words-as-text-part-to-multi-part-request-in-volley-lib)